# Time difference with a field

Tags: sql, oracle, select, timezone

I have a date field and a timezone-difference field with a +/-. **I want to calculate the local time.**

**Example:** *(from UTC to LAX)*

`SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU      20-APR-20 04.20.00.00000000`   *(This is in UTC)*

`utc_var_dep_hrs        -7`        *(LAX is -7 hrs from UTC)*

When I try `SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU + utc_var_dep_hrs`, **it considers the `-7` as days instead of hours** and thus result is `13-APR-20`. The result should be `19-APR-20 09.20.00.000000`.

I have tried various `to_char`, but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU + utc_var_dep_hrs * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
```

An alternative is:

```
SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU + utc_var_dep_hrs / 24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordons answers are good candidates or you can use the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function:

```
SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU + NUMTODSINTERVAL(UTC_VAR_DEP_HRS,'hour')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not just add/subtract a fixed number of hours as then you will get the wrong time when the time zone changes to/from daylight savings time.

Instead, store your values as UTC and then convert to a time zone rather than converting by adding an interval. To do this, you can use `FROM_TZ` to convert your `TIMESTAMP` data type to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and then use `AT TIME ZONE` to convert from one time zone to another:

```sql
SELECT FROM_TZ( sched_dep_date_bu, 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS sched_dep_date_bu_pst
FROM   table_name;
```

If your data is:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( sched_dep_date_bu )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-04-20 04:20:00.00000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-03-08 09:59:59.00000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-03-08 10:00:00.00000000' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can compare the above output to just adding 7 hours with:

```sql
SELECT sched_dep_date_bu - INTERVAL '7' HOUR AS sched_dep_date_bu_7,
       FROM_TZ( sched_dep_date_bu, 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS sched_dep_date_bu_pst
FROM   table_name;
```

and the output is:

> ```
> SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU_7           | SCHED_DEP_DATE_BU_PST             
> :---------------------------- | :---------------------------------
> 2020-04-19 21:20:00.000000000 | 2020-04-19 21:20:00.000000000-0700
> 2020-03-08 02:59:59.000000000 | 2020-03-08 01:59:59.000000000-0800
> 2020-03-08 03:00:00.000000000 | 2020-03-08 03:00:00.000000000-0700
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ced8130f2b91ce35fbd896824a69d349)*

`2020-03-08 02:59:59.000000000` is a time that does not exist as `PST` was at an 8-hour time difference and then went to daylight savings time for the 1st and 3rd rows.